# Cannot add FOREIGN KEY constraint using ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

everybody, I am relatively new to SQL and I am currently testing my database tables using Oracle Live SQL. I have a table called Customer and a table called Contact. Within the Contact table, I am trying to add a FOREIGN KEY constraint of the Customer_ID column into my Contact table, but keep getting an ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_ID": invalid identifier, error using the code below:

```
ALTER TABLE Contact ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a Customer_ID field in your Contact table?

Comment: No I have a Customer_ID column in my Customer Table

Comment: and in Contact id  which column name you have?  .add your schema  .. +

Comment: Please show the ddl for your table(s) and describe the relationship you're trying to codify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you don't have the column `Customer_Id` in `contact`.  So try this:

```
ALTER TABLE Contact ADD Customer_Id number;  -- the type is a guess

ALTER TABLE Contact ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID);
```

Comment: WOW I cannot believe I forgot to even add the column Customer_ID into the Contact table. Thank you very much this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So based on the comments on your question, you don't have a Customer_ID column on your Contact table. The definition of a foreign key is that you have the column you want to reference in both tables.

```
ALTER TABLE Contact ADD Customer_ID int;
ALTER TABLE Contact ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're correct, I forgot to add a column name in the Contact table called Customer_ID